# Development environment; Win7+Ubuntu (RoR, MySQL, PHP, Apache)

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu

I just erased a hard drive from my old system and would like to install Ubuntu on it along with PHP, RoR, MySQL and Apache to be my development environment.  My primary HDD is Win7.

If I do the majority of my work in Win7 and save to the 2nd HDD (Ubuntu), can I access my development sites on Ubuntu as if it were in a separate box?  Would all my paths be by drive letter instead of by IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use virtualization to accomplish this.  Adding another hard drive doesn't automatically give you any IPs.  You still have just your regular outside-facing IP (LAN or WAN) and your loopback (127.0.0.1).

You can read these [VirtualBox instructions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) on setting up an internal network, with each virtual guest having its own local IP.  Other virtualization software has similar capabilities.

EDIT: If you just want to serve from a directory on D, you can customize [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) to be e.g.

```
DocumentRoot "D:/public_html"
```

Comment: Hey Matthew, I wasn't looking to have it be an IP, I was just wondering if by having Ubuntu on one HDD and doing work in Win7 if the Ubuntu HDD would serve up the pages like a separate dev server and if I would need to access it by drive letter vs an IP since its in the same box.

Comment: @Brandon, you can only have one webservice listening on each IP-port combination.  So to do have drive addressing, you'd have to set up Apache to serve pages from both drives with something like `localhost/c/proj1/foo.php` and `localhost/d/proj2/bar.php`.  That is probably doable, but it doesn't seem that clean.  You would want to be careful Apache isn't serving your entire machine.

Comment: I would most likely just serve pages from D:/ Any other suggestions?  I just want to have one drive for dev work and one drive as my primary OS/Apps.

Comment: @Brandon, then all you really need to do is customize `DocumentRoot`.